# A question on the Brewers' Friend Calculator

Tags: first-time-brewer, extract-brewing, ibu

Does anyone know, for when using the [calculator, for extract brewing](http://www.brewersfriend.com/homebrew/recipe/calculator/), at what time the calculator assumes you add the malt (liquid malt extract in my case)? I.e. does it assume late addition or full 60 min. boil? I am asking because I want to get to as close to the predicted IBU level of my beer as possible for my boil size. As I understand, AA extraction can be affected (reduced?) by the sugars in the wort.

Thanks.

Comment: Which calculator in particular do you mean? Can you link to it, perhaps?

Comment: Please see link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fermentables section, if you "Add Custom" you can indicate that a fermentable (extract) addition is a "Late Addition", but it does not seem to specify exactly when/how late that addition is; I imagine it means "near flameout".  As such, it looks like it will account for bitterness changes.

You should probably inquire with the Brewers Friend authors/operators, honestly.

Comment: Thanks jsled. I literally just stumbled across this when I saw a drop down menu. If I check the late addition box it increases my IBUs 3 fold! (Up to 333 - lol.) This has confirmed for me that I will be adding all of my malt at the start of the boil :)